# elmah recording 400 and 404 erros with random urls

Tags: .net, iis, elmah, windows-update

I have elmah integrated with a .net application on an IIS 7.5 server.  Occasionally, elmah will show a string of 400 and 404 error with very erroneous urls:

```
Path_Info : /level/7/exec/-/".<EEYE_2009_XSS_TAG>
Path_Info : /index.php/Special:Version
Path_Info : /loyalty_enu/start.swe/>"><script>alert('XSS')</script>
Path_Info : /IISADMPWD/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/winnt/system32/cmd.exe
Path_Info : /cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/winnt/system32/cmd.exe
Path_Info : /msadc/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/winnt/system32/cmd.exe
Path_Info : /pls/sample/admin_/help/..%5cplsql.conf
Path_Info : /_vti_bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/winnt/system32/cmd.exe
Path_Info : /scripts/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/winnt/system32/cmd.exe
```

No users are logged in when these errors occur, and there is no reason for the code to use these url extensions.

My theories are:
 - Security software (Mcafee) is running a check for security vulnerabilities/running updates
 - Windows Updates are causing this
 - Someone is trying to hack the application/server.

Any ideas?